# How to create FIle object from base64 to sent it Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

On client side i have some code

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create_post/'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token c63ee5854eb60618b8940829d2f64295d6201a96'}
image_string = None

with open("21485.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    image_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

data ={ 'text':'new_post_python', 
        'image':image_string
    }

requests.post(url, json=data,headers=headers)
```

and i want to create some post through api

on server side i have such code

```
class CreatePostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        Post.objects.create(
            text=data.get('text'),
            author=request.user,
            image=...,
        )
        return Response({'created': True})
```

Where from .models

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', blank=True, null=True)
```

How can i built image from base64 string on server side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will give you an idea:

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
path=PATH_OF_FILE
with open(path, "rb") as image_file:
    data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
im.save(SAVE_AS)
```

hint: You pass data from the client-side and receive the data variable by the server-side and simply decode the base64 string to image and save in the directory...

Comment: Thank a lot, i have done it but after that i have image not same dimensions. How can i get image the same dimensions ?